# Submitting Ajax Form From Ajax Loaded Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a page which is generated within ajax.

On that page there is a 2 forms, #form1 and #form2.

I have the jquery the code for submitting the form is as follows:

```
jQuery("#form1").on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var sendurl = '/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.php';

        var varable1 = jQuery('#infor1').val();
        var varable2 = jQuery('#infor2').val();
        var varable3 = jQuery('#infor3').val();
        var varable4 = jQuery('#infor4').val();
        var varable5 = jQuery('#infor5').val();
        var varable6 = jQuery('#infor6').val();
        var varable7 = jQuery('#infor7').val();

        jQuery.ajax({url: sendurl + '?varable1=varable1' + 'varable2=' + varable2 + 'varable3=' + varable3 + 'varable4=' + varable4 + 'varable5=' + varable5 + 'varable6=' + varable6 + 'varable7=' + varable7}).done(function(data) {

            if(data === 'fail'){
                jQuery('.error').html('Something went wrong with your form request please try again!').slideDown(500).delay(4000).slideUp(500);
                jQuery('input[type=submit]', jQuery("#submittions")).removeAttr('disabled');
                return false;
            }

            if(data !== 'fail'){
                jQuery('#showresults').slideUp(600);
                jQuery('.show-complete-detail').html(data);
                jQuery('#applicationcomplete').delay(1500).slideDown(400);
            }

        }); 
});
```

I have also tried the:

```
jQuery().submit();
```

That does not work either.

I am assuming that because the page is loaded in using ajax that it can not find the form with the id of form1?

Has anyone any ideas on where I am going wrong.

Thanks :)

Comment: it would be ok if you bind event after the form is appended to document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically loaded content, use event delegation like so :

```
// replacing document with top level parent
// something like parent container
jQuery(document).on('submit','#form1', function(e){ ... }
```

And one more thing, data passed from ajax url like that is bad idea, you should use data properties to send data, see below example :

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'POST', // or GET
     url : 'your url here',
     data : {
        var1 : variable1
         .......
     },
    .... Another properties...
 }).done(data){...});
```

Comment: thanks for the advice and pointer on what I need to do... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event to a higher level dom element that wasnt added dynamically.

ie)

```
$("#FormContainer").on("#form1", "submit",function(){
    //   Do Form tuff....
});
$("#FormContainer").on("#form", "submit",function(){
   //   Do Form tuff....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

bind with document

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#form1', function(e){


});
```

use the console.log for sendurl

```
console.log(sendurl)
```